# How do I get the Gravity Suit?

Tags: jetpack-joyride

I am trying to do the mission "Change gravity 30 times in one run". I know you have to use a Gravity Suit but how do I get it? I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 3):

You could find a more detailed explanation of the answer [HERE](http://jetpackjoyride.wikia.com/wiki/Gravity_Suit).
However, this is a basic breakdown for you.

**The Gravity suit, though it does not look like one, is classified as a vehicle. And like other vehicles, it can be acquired through the same means. Through that rainbow colored gear gem like the following:** [image]
Since your chances of getting it is random, it will take some playing before you can get to it.

**TIP: A handy tip would be that once you get the suit, just starting rapidly tapping the screen. Tap it 30 times and you are done.**

Answer (score 0):

Just keep playing and you'll find some bubbles with a metal thing inside, there's a chance it could be the gravity suit